# Как именованный кортеж добавить в словарь?

Tags: python, словари, коллекции, tuple

В функцию передают список именнованных кортежей с котиками. Функция должна возвращать список словарей с "ключами" именованного кортежа. У меня в итоге добавляется только последний котик. И можно ли как-нибудь напрямую взять "ключи" кортежа и сделать из них ключи словаря чтобы не прописывать вручную строчку для каждого ключа?

```
import collections

Cat = collections.namedtuple("Cat", ["nickname", "age", "owner"])

def convert_list(cats):
    to_dict = {}
    list_of_dict_cats = []
    if isinstance(cats[0], tuple):
        for cat in cats:
            to_dict['nickname'] = cat.nickname
            to_dict['age'] = cat.age
            to_dict['owner'] = cat.owner
            list_of_dict_cats.append(to_dict)
    print(list_of_dict_cats)


convert_list([Cat("Mick", 5, "Sara"), Cat("Barsik", 7, "Olga"), Cat("Simon", 3, "Yura")])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно перенести создание словаря `to_dict` внутрь цикла. Из-за того что вы создаете словарь до цикла, в список каждый раз добавляется один и тот же словарь. Все элементы списка у вас - это один и тот же словарь, и изменения в словаре отображаются во всех элементах списка.

Проверку `isinstance(cats[0], tuple)`, если она действительно нужна, лучше внести в цикл, т.к. то что первый элемент списка - `tuple`, не гарантирует, что другие элементы - тоже `tuple`. К тому же, при типа значения первого элемента у вас отсутствует проверка, что список не пустой, но если внести проверку в цикл, то дополнительная проверка будет не нужна.

И то что объект - `tuple` не гарантирует, что у объекта будут поля `nickname`, `age`, `owner`, поэтому лучше явно проверять, что объект относится к классу `Cat`

```
for cat in cats:
    if isinstance(cat, Cat):
        to_dict = {}
        to_dict['nickname'] = cat.nickname
        to_dict['age'] = cat.age
        to_dict['owner'] = cat.owner
        list_of_dict_cats.append(to_dict)
```

Также, для преобразования `namedtuple` в словарь можно использовать метод [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict):

```
for cat in cats:
    if isinstance(cat, Cat):
        list_of_dict_cats.append(cat._asdict())
```

Ну и по условию вам нужно создать функцию, которая должна возвращать список словарей, а вы его печатаете, вместо этого нужно делать `return list_of_dict_cats`, а результат функции уже печатать:

```
import collections

Cat = collections.namedtuple("Cat", ["nickname", "age", "owner"])

def convert_list(cats):
    list_of_dict_cats = []

    for cat in cats:
        if isinstance(cat, Cat):
            list_of_dict_cats.append(cat._asdict())
    
    return list_of_dict_cats


print(convert_list([Cat("Mick", 5, "Sara"), Cat("Barsik", 7, "Olga"), Cat("Simon", 3, "Yura")]))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, я нашел метод _addict, хотелось бы просто узнать как это можно было реализовать вручную. Ваши проверки очень полезные